# Using GraphQL's union with apollo-react in react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm currently using react-apollo in a react-native app and I'm facing an issue.

Whenever I try to make a query containing an union, it fails, throwing the following network error:

> Network error: Requested keys of a value that is not an object

I'm using the exact same code in a React.js app, which works just fine. The GraphQL endpoint is my own server, developed in PHP with the Youshido bundle.

Here's the fragment declaration part :

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: 'http://10.1.68.64:8000/graphql'});

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
    introspectionQueryResultData: {
      __schema: {
        types: [
          {
            "kind": "UNION",
            "name": "QuestionUnion",
            "possibleTypes": [
              {
                "name": "QuestionUnionTypeA"
              },
              {
                "name": "QuestionUnionTypeB"
              },
              {
                "name": "QuestionUnionTypeC"
              }
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
    }
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher });

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: cache,
});
```

The query in a Screen.js file (Exactly the same in React.js and react-native):

```
const FindForm = gql`query FindForm($id: ID!){
    findForm(id: $id){
        id
        title
        questions {
            id
            ... on QuestionUnionTypeA {
                parameterA
            } 
            ... on QuestionUnionTypeB {
                parameterB
            }
            ... on QuestionUnionTypeC {
                parameterC
            }
        }
    }
}`;
```

The part using the query in the same Screen.js file:

```
const resultDisplayer = ({ data }) => {
    if(data.error){
        return <Text> {JSON.stringify(data)} </Text>;
    }
    if(data.loading){
        return <Spinner/>;
    }
    else {
        return <Text> Ok </Text>;
    }
};

const query = graphql(FindForm, {
    options: {
        variables: {
            id: this.state.id,
        }
    }
})(resultDisplayer);
```

The troubling part is that the error is not thrown in a few cases:

- When I'm remotely debugging the app
- When the query does not contain the union part
- When the union part has nothing to return (If there are no instance of QuestionUnionTypeA, B and C)

Thus I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to find where I've been mistaken. If you guys have any idea, I'm willing to try anything that comes up.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got a similar problem. Everything's fine running a query in standard react-dom, or remote debugging in react-native, then as soon as I'm on the device I get the same error you're seeing.

Comment: i am getting this error on android only (emulator & device) everything works in ios

Comment: @BaronVonKaneHoffen Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't able to find a solution and moved on without using unions. However, if you ever find something, I'd really like to know how you did, because changing all my back-end logic was time consuming and kind of heartbreaking

Comment: @R.Duteil Ha I ended up abandoning Apollo entirely and switched to Firebase / Firestore. Litterally took me 2 days with that to get as far as I'd got with Apollo + AWS AppSync / Lambda / DynamoDB etc. in a month. Great docs + really simple. Depends what you're doing though I guess.